# Windows batch file: How to make a hidden or system file read-only (or not read-only) while retaining its hidden and system attributes?

Tags: windows, batch-file

The `attrib` command is used to change file attributes such as hidden, system, read-only, and archive.

The problem is that you can't change the read-only status of a hidden or system file - without additionally clearing *or setting* the hidden or system status.  For example:

```
C:\somewhere>REM Set up a hidden test file.
C:\somewhere>echo foo > foo.txt
C:\somewhere>attrib +h foo.txt

C:\somewhere>REM Try to make the hidden test file read-only.
C:\somewhere>attrib +r foo.txt
Not resetting hidden file - C:\somewhere\foo.txt

C:\somewhere>REM We can make it read-only if we additionally clear the hidden status...
C:\somewhere>attrib -h +r foo.txt

C:\somewhere>REM (Revert that last change.)
C:\somewhere>attrib +h -r foo.txt

C:\somewhere>REM ...and we can make it read-only if we additionally make it hidden - which it already is.
C:\somewhere>attrib +h +r foo.txt
C:\somewhere>
```

(I'm assuming the system attribute works the same way as above but I haven't tested.)

So `attrib` will work for this purpose - but only if the batch file knows whether the file is *already* hidden or system, and can then include the appropriate `+h` or `+s` along with the `+r`.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: List the attributes of the file first and save them to a variable.

Comment: Right.  I was hoping that there's an incantation that avoids manually parsing `attrib`'s output.

Answer (score 0):

Save the hidden and system attributes in a variable, clear and reapply when needed.

Usage:

```dos
call :setAttr "+r -a" "file"
call :setAttr +r "file"
call :setAttr -r "file"
```

The function:

```dos
:setAttr
    :: Usage:
    ::  call :setAttr "+r -a" "file"
    setlocal

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('attrib "%~2"') do set "attrs=%%a"
    set "attrs=%attrs:~0,10%"

    set toggle=
    if not "%attrs:H=%"=="%attrs%" set toggle=-h
    if not "%attrs:S=%"=="%attrs%" set toggle=%toggle% -s

    if defined toggle attrib %toggle% "%~2"
    attrib %~1 "%~2"
    if defined toggle attrib %toggle:-=+% "%~2"

    endlocal
    exit /b
```